Exit strategy/options for an existing 1031 exchange
I own 10 units that I purchased on one note with the proceeds of a 1031 back in 2020.  They are a 4 plex and a 6 plex.
Can I sell one of the two buildings and retain the other?  What are the implications on the 1031? Can I keep all the 1031 rollover/basis/capital gain inside the one I hold?  Do I need to split everything proportionally?
For simplicity, my last rollover was $400k, my new 10 units were $70k each. I had about $200k in cash from the proceeds of the 1031. If I sell 6 now, at $600k, and retain 4 at $400k what is the impact for me in terms of both the new capital gain, but also the rollover portion?  If I sell 60% of the property, do I do 60% of the cap gain (including the 1031)?  Do it all? Keep it all in the unsold portion?
Phew.  Hopefully that makes sense.
A follow up would be, can I buy (with the 1031 proceeds) a multi-use or multi-family building, and live in any part of it? I know I can't buy specifically a primary residence.


Can I sell one of the two buildings and retain the other

Yes, I would assume these are separate parcels.

What are the implications on the 1031

None.

Can I keep all the 1031 rollover/basis/cap gain inside the one I hold

No.

Do I need to split everything proprotionally

You need to calculate the basis in each of the properties and adjust it by the deferred gains accordingly. You would probably want to use a licensed CPA to do that for you.

can I buy (with the 1031 proceeds) a multi-use or multi-family building, and live in any part of it?

You can not use the 1031 proceeds for your personal residence.

Thank you for those answers.

One follow up question - if I sell them both on separate contracts. Can I roll one into a 1031 (with the proportional basis you mention) and 'realize' the gain on the other one (IE not put it in a 1031)?

You don't put anything into 1031. Section 1031 allows deferring taxes on gains if you buy a replacement property. That's it. Noone can force you buy anything.
